# Tmux - Set Truecolor Status-Line

Tags: terminal, tmux, color-scheme, neovim

I use iTerm2 with tmux 2.6. Since I added the lines

```
set-option -ga terminal-overrides ",xterm-256color:Tc"
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

into my `.tmux.conf` truecolor works fine with neovim. Now I want the tmux-status line to have the same color as my vim-airline.

So my question is how I can set the color of the tmux statusline with a truecolor value?